# SQL Nth Day of Nth Week of a Month

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I want to use the following function for scheduling club meetings which occur on a monthly basis based on the week and weekday of the month.  In the example below I have a (to be) function that returns the Third Wednesday of the month.  If that day occurs in the past then it returns the next month's 3rd Wednesday.

I want to get away from the Loops and I feel that there is a better method for calculation.  Is there a more OO process?  Your opinion?

```
--CREATE FUNCTION NextWeekDayofMonth

DECLARE 
--(
        @WEEK INT,
        @WEEKDAY INT,
        @REFERENCEDATE DATETIME
--) 
--RETURNS DATETIME
--AS

-------------------------------
--Values for testing - Third Wednesday of the Month
set @WEEK = 3   --Third Week
set @WEEKDAY = 4    --Wednesday
set @REFERENCEDATE = '08/20/2011'
-------------------------------

BEGIN

    DECLARE @WEEKSEARCH INT
    DECLARE @FDOM DATETIME
    DECLARE @RETURNDATE DATETIME
    SET @FDOM = DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,@REFERENCEDATE),0)
    SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(M,0,@FDOM)


    WHILE (@RETURNDATE < @REFERENCEDATE)
    --If the calculated date occurs in the past then it 
    --finds the appropriate date in the next month
    BEGIN

    SET @WEEKSEARCH = 1
    SET @RETURNDATE = @FDOM

    --Finds the first weekday of the month that matches the provided weekday value
        WHILE ( DATEPART(DW,@RETURNDATE) <> @WEEKDAY)
            BEGIN
            SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(D,1,@RETURNDATE)
            END

    --Iterates through the weeks without going into next month
        WHILE @WEEKSEARCH < @WEEK
            BEGIN
            IF MONTH(DATEADD(WK,1,@RETURNDATE)) = MONTH(@FDOM) 
                BEGIN
                    SET @RETURNDATE = DATEADD(WK,1,@RETURNDATE)
                    SET @WEEKSEARCH = @WEEKSEARCH+1
                END 
                ELSE
                    BREAK
            END
        SET @FDOM = DATEADD(M,1,@FDOM)
    END

    --RETURN @RETURNDATE
    select @ReturnDate
    END
```

Comment: Checkout the following post, it looks like it could help you: [Calculating Nth weekday in a month](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/calculating-nth-weekday-in-a-month)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first Sunday of next month using T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506036/get-first-sunday-of-next-month-using-t-sql)

Comment: jdavies - Great Link.  I will add both your and catcalls solutions to my notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the best process is to store important business information as rows in tables in a database. If you build a calendar table, you can get all the third Wednesdays by a simple query. Not only are the queries simple, *they can be seen to be obviously correct*.

```
select cal_date 
from calendar
where day_of_week_ordinal = 3
  and day_of_week = 'Wed';
```

The third Wednesday that's on or after today is also simple.

```
select min(cal_date)
from calendar
where day_of_week_ordinal = 3
  and day_of_week = 'Wed'
  and cal_date >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Creating a calendar table is straightforward. This was written for PostgreSQL, but it's entirely standard SQL (I think) except for the columns relating to ISO years and ISO weeks.

```
create table calendar (
  cal_date date primary key,
  year_of_date integer not null 
    check (year_of_date = extract(year from cal_date)),
  month_of_year integer not null 
    check (month_of_year = extract(month from cal_date)),
  day_of_month integer not null 
    check (day_of_month = extract(day from cal_date)),
  day_of_week char(3) not null 
    check (day_of_week = 
    case when extract(dow from cal_date) = 0 then 'Sun'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 1 then 'Mon'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 2 then 'Tue'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 3 then 'Wed'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 4 then 'Thu'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 5 then 'Fri'
         when extract(dow from cal_date) = 6 then 'Sat'
    end),
  day_of_week_ordinal integer not null
    check (day_of_week_ordinal = 
      case
        when day_of_month >= 1 and day_of_month <= 7 then 1
        when day_of_month >= 8 and day_of_month <= 14 then 2
        when day_of_month >= 15 and day_of_month <= 21 then 3
        when day_of_month >= 22 and day_of_month <= 28 then 4
        else 5
      end),
  iso_year integer not null 
    check (iso_year = extract(isoyear from cal_date)),
  iso_week integer not null 
    check (iso_week = extract(week from cal_date))
);
```

You can populate that table with a spreadsheet or with a UDF. Spreadsheets usually have pretty good date and time functions. I have a UDF, but it's written for PostgreSQL (PL/PGSQL), so I'm not sure how much it would help you. But I'll post it later if you like.

Comment: A tally table.  That's brilliant and fast.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a date math way to accomplish what you want without looping:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Description: Gets the nth occurrence of a given weekday in the month containing the specified date.
-- For @dayOfWeek, 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, 3 = Tuesday, 4 = Wednesday, 5 = Thursday, 6 = Friday, 7 = Saturday
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION GetWeekdayInMonth 
(
    @date datetime,
    @dayOfWeek int,
    @nthWeekdayInMonth int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @beginMonth datetime
    DECLARE @offSet int
    DECLARE @firstWeekdayOfMonth datetime
    DECLARE @result datetime

    SET @beginMonth = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, @date) + 1, @date)
    SET @offSet = @dayOfWeek - DATEPART(dw, @beginMonth)

    IF (@offSet < 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @firstWeekdayOfMonth = DATEADD(d, 7 + @offSet, @beginMonth)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @firstWeekdayOfMonth = DATEADD(d, @offSet, @beginMonth)
    END

    SET @result = DATEADD(WEEK, @nthWeekdayInMonth - 1, @firstWeekdayOfMonth)

    IF (NOT(MONTH(@beginMonth) = MONTH(@result)))
    BEGIN
        SET @result = NULL
    END

    RETURN @result
END
GO

DECLARE @nextMeetingDate datetime

SET @nextMeetingDate = dbo.GetWeekdayInMonth(GETDATE(), 4, 3)
IF (@nextMeetingDate IS NULL OR @nextMeetingDate < GETDATE())
BEGIN
    SET @nextMeetingDate = dbo.GetWeekDayInMonth(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()), 4, 3)
END

SELECT @nextMeetingDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another function based solution using date math that returns the Next Nth Weekday on or after a given date.  It doesn't use any looping to speak of, but it may recurs by at most one iteration if the next Nth weekday is in the next month.

This function takes the DATEFIRST setting into account for environments that use a value other than the default.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      David Grimberg
-- Create date: 2015-06-18
-- Description: Gets the next Nth weekday
-- @param Date is any date in a month
-- @param DayOfWeek is the weekday of interest ranging
--            from 1 to 7 with @@DATEFIRST being the
--            first day of the week
-- @param NthWeekday represents which ordinal weekday to return.
--            Positive values return dates relative to the start
--            of the month.  Negative values return dates relative
--            to the end of the month.  Values > 4 indicate the 
--            last week, values < -4 indicate the first week.
--            Zero is assumed to be 1.
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.xxGetNextNthWeekday
(
  @Date       date,
  @NthWeekday smallint,
  @DayOfWeek  tinyint
)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @FirstOfMonth date
  DECLARE @inc int
    DECLARE @Result date

  -- Clamp the @NthWeekday input to valid values
  set @NthWeekday = case when @NthWeekday = 0 then 1
                         when @NthWeekday > 4 then -1
                         when @NthWeekday < -4 then 1
                         else @NthWeekday
                    end

  -- Normalize the requested day of week taking
  -- @@DATEFIRST into consideration.
    set @DayOfWeek = (@@DATEFIRST + 6 + @DayOfWeek) % 7 + 1

  -- Gets the first of the current month or the
  -- next month if @NthWeekday is negative.
  set @FirstOfMonth = dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,@Date)
                                   + case when @NthWeekday < 0 then 1 else 0 end
                                   , 0)

  -- Add and/or subtract 1 week depending direction of search and the
  -- relationship of @FirstOfMonth's Day of the Week to the @DayOfWeek
  -- of interest
  set @inc = case when (datepart(WEEKDAY, @FirstOfMonth)+@@DATEFIRST-1)%7+1 > @DayOfWeek
                  then 0 
                  else -1
             end
           + case when @NthWeekday < 0 then 1 else 0 end

  -- Put it all together
  set @Result = dateadd( day
                       , @DayOfWeek-1
                       , dateadd( WEEK
                                , @NthWeekday + @inc
                                , dateadd( WEEK -- Gets 1st Sunday on or
                                         , datediff(WEEK, -1, @FirstOfMonth)
                                         ,-1 ) ) )  -- before @FirstOfMonth
  -- [Snip here] --
  if @Result < @Date 
    set @Result = dbo.xxGetNextNthWeekday( dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @Date)+1, 0)
                                         , @NthWeekday, @DayOfWeek)
  -- [to here for no recursion] --

  Return @Result
END
```

If you want the past or future Nth weekday of the current month based on the @Date parameter rather than the next Nth weekday snip out the recursive part as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a tally table was right for me.  We have a location scheduler where locations are "1st and 3rd Saturdays" or "3rd Monday of each month".
So what are the 3rd Monday's for the next 10 years?

[image: Here's and example of the dates that are the 3rd Monday for the next 10 years]

```
Declare @startFromDate date = '05/01/2023' --MUST BE THE 1ST OF THE MONTH
declare @DayOfMonthIndexMapper TABLE (
  DayOfMonth tinyint, InstanceMap tinyint
) Insert Into @DayOfMonthIndexMapper 
SELECT 
  top 31 number as rn, 
  Case when number < 8 Then 1 --the first 7 days of the month are the first instance for those dayofweekIndexes below
  when number between 8 
  and 14 then 2 --the second 7 days..etc
  when number between 15 
  and 21 then 3 when number between 22 
  and 28 then 4 else 5 END InstanceMap 
FROM 
  master..spt_values stupidtable 
where 
  type = 'p' 
  and number > 0;
--start CTE
With DateSeeder as (
  Select 
    top 3650 dummytable.myrownumber, 
    Cast(
      dateadd(
        dd, dummytable.myrownumber - 1, @startFromDate
      ) as DateTime
    ) as TallyDate, 
    DATEPART(
      d, 
      dateadd(
        dd, dummytable.myrownumber - 1, @startFromDate
      )
    ) mydayofmonth, 
    DATEPART(
      dw, 
      dateadd(
        dd, dummytable.myrownumber - 1, @startFromDate
      )
    ) dayofweekIndex, 
    DATEPART(
      month, 
      dateadd(
        dd, dummytable.myrownumber - 1, @startFromDate
      )
    ) as monthnumber 
  from 
    (
      SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          ORDER BY 
            (
              SELECT 
                NULL
            )
        ) AS myrownumber 
      FROM 
        [master].[sys].[all_columns]
    ) dummytable
)

Select TallyDate,dayofweekIndex,InstanceMap from DateSeeder
  inner join @DayOfMonthIndexMapper dmim on DateSeeder.mydayofmonth=dmim.DayOfMonth
  Where dayofweekIndex=2 and InstanceMap=3
```

**Please note - the references to the master table are just to pull a bunch of rows - instead of seeding the table with a loop from 1 to 10000, I can join on master to generate rownumbers**

1. The Table Variable @DayOfMonthIndexMapper has 31 rows (max number of days in a month), and then it has 7 rows of 1s, 7 rows of 2s, 7 rows of 3s, 7 rows of 4s, and 3 rows of 5s.
2. The CTE DateSeeder pulls 3650 rows (about 10 years) with the date and the dayofweekindex (where Sunday=1) and a dayofmonth (1 to 31).
3. So joining the DateSeeder.mydayofmonth to dayOfMonthIndexMapper.mydayofmonth allows a lookup to the instance map.

I went ahead and just inserted this into a tallytable on the server, but I suppose it could be a view or function that you could query